# sem_post does not prioritise sem_wait call in other thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore, exit

I am working on my project where it is crucial that everything is cleaned up properly and all buffered log messages are saved to a file etc.. I am calling exit from another thread and I was thinking to use a semaphore to wait for the cleanup in main thread to occur before the program fully exits. The problem is that when I call sem_post from my exit handler registred with atexit, sem_wait will not immediately decrement the semaphore thus sem_wait in my exit handler will exit immediately because the semaphore is greater than zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static sem_t sem;

void *do_work(void *arg) {
  // if something fails
  printf("Something failed!\n");
  exit(1);
}

void exit_handler() {
  sem_post(&sem); // wake up main thread
  sem_wait(&sem); // wait for cleanup in main
  sem_destroy(&sem);
}

int main() {
  pthread_t worker_thread;

  sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
  atexit(exit_handler);

  pthread_create(&worker_thread, NULL, do_work, NULL);

  sem_wait(&sem); // block this thread until work is done

  // simulate some cleanup
  usleep(1000000);
  printf("This never gets called!\n");

  sem_post(&sem); // destroy semaphore
}
```

This [example](https://ideone.com/H3ZcUw) demonstrates my problem. Is there any solution to this problem? I mustn't put the cleanup in my exit handler because I have a lot of local resources in the main function that needs to be cleaned up in my actual program.

Comment: @Mat sorry, forgot to include that. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I do not see the benefit of sem_* here. Can't you just use pthread_join() to wait for thread termination and make the cleanup then?

Comment: @Ctx Well, in this particular case I could. However there are a lot of other threads in my actual program that needs to be terminated and other operations that must be done in main because I don't want to overuse global variables for every resource I use.

Comment: Since I do not know the actual code it is hard to say, but I would happily trade some space for many more global variables to get rid of constructs like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control which thread will return from `sem_wait()` after a call to `sem_post()`.  You need to use two semaphores:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static sem_t wakeupMain;
static sem_t cleanupDone;

void *do_work(void *arg) {
  // if something fails
  printf("Something failed!\n");
  exit(1);
}

void exit_handler() {
  sem_post(&wakeupMain); // wake up main thread
  sem_wait(&cleanupDone); // wait for cleanup in main
  sem_destroy(&wakeupMain);
  sem_destroy(&cleanupDone);
}

int main() {
  pthread_t worker_thread;

  sem_init(&wakeupMain, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&cleanupDone, 0, 0);
  atexit(exit_handler);

  pthread_create(&worker_thread, NULL, do_work, NULL);

  sem_wait(&wakeupMain); // block this thread until work is done

  // simulate some cleanup
  usleep(1000000);
  printf("This never gets called!\n");

  sem_post(&cleanupDone); // destroy semaphore
}
```

Comment: To add to this, the *reason* it's not possible to guarantee that the other thread will be woken before the atexit handler calls its own `sem_wait` is that there is no way to observe whether the other thread is "waiting in `sem_wait`" or "just about to call `sem_wait`". While the latter should be unlikely, without further synchronization, you cannot prove it's not the case, and thus you can't assume it.

Comment: @R.. Indeed.  And even if the other thread is blocked in `sem_wait()`, there's no guarantee that the already-running thread that called `sem_post()` won't be the one that acquires the semaphore via `sem_wait()`.  I'd even venture to guess that's likely, as the OS's scheduler would be able to just "give" the semaphore to an already-running thread instead of having to block that thread and perform a context switch to the other thread.

Comment: Well formally it's required to unblock an existing waiter if there is one. The only thing that allows an implementation not to do this is the "as if" rule and the inability to observe whether another thread is already waiting or about-to-wait.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, I assumed that whenever you call sem_post the sem_wait would return based on when it was called, sort of like when you call sem_wait it adds it to a fifo queue. Nevertheless isn't there another way to overcome this problem using only one semaphore? Or even a better way without using semaphores at all?

Comment: @R.. *Well formally it's required to unblock an existing waiter if there is one. ...*  Hmm, this [glibc source code](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_wait.c?!v=glibc-2.17) seems to indicate that if a thread calls `sem_wait()` on Linux and the semaphore value is positive the running thread won't even try to wake up any thread that might be waiting.

Comment: @Linus Any thread waiting for a synchronization object isn't in a queue, it's in a pool.  You never know which thread will acquire whatever object the threads are all waiting for.  And how do you define "when it was called" when waiting for an object from different CPUs?  How would you define "first" or "simultaneous"? Once you start making ordering assumptions, definitions like that become critical. Read the [first 200 lines or so of comments at the top of this source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/futex.c) for some idea what that entails.

Comment: @Linus - This [Solaris `sem_wait()` source code](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/port/threads/sema.c#82) might be of interest.  Note that the comments state that SUSv3 requires FIFO queuing for semaphores.  I was unaware of that, and apparently Linux and glibc don't follow that requirement, assuming you're running on Linux.

Comment: @AndrewHenle okay, I think I have a somewhat better understanding of how it works now. I guess my best shot is to use two semaphores. Thanks for the explanation and pardon for my ignorance. I am very new to semaphores.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The "requirement of fifo ordering" for semaphores, if one exists, is vacuous because entering the queue is not observable. In reality there is not even such a nominal requirement.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE The  [POSIX 7 `sem_post()` page states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/sem_post.html): "In the case of the schedulers SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR, the highest priority waiting thread shall be unblocked, and if there is more than one highest priority thread blocked waiting for the semaphore, then the highest priority thread that has been waiting the longest shall be unblocked. If the Process Scheduling option is not defined, the choice of a thread to unblock is unspecified."  Vacuous or not, that's what it says.  Yeah, I'm slow... ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: OK, indeed there is something written but it's not meaningful because there's no difference on the abstract machine between a high priority thread being blocked on the semaphore and it being blocked on a TLB miss and page fault on the instruction just prior to calling sem_wait.